# how to upload and view a PDF file in angular using Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm working with angular and ionic at the moment and I need to be able to upload and view a PDF file. So far I can choose the pdf file, however I'm having issues with upload it. This is my code thus far

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<ion-button  onclick="uploadPDF()" name="submit">
  Upload File
</ion-button>


<script>
  function uploadPDF() {
  let data = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  let entry = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  console.log('uploadPDF',entry,data)
  fetch('uploads/' + encodeURIComponent(entry.name), {method:'PUT',body:data});
  alert('your file has been uploaded');
  location.reload();
};
</script>
```

When the `upload file` button is clicked a prompt should appear that says 'your file has been uploaded' however this does not occur

Answer (score 1):

You have to use these two plugins:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer

You can upload the file to your server and then get the URL to view it in the app.